# angularjs directive - get element bound text content

Tags: angularjs

How do you get the value of the binding based on an angular js directive `restrict: 'A'`?

```
<span directiverestrict> {{binding}} </span>
```

I tried using `elem[0].innerText` but it returns the exact binding `'{{binding}}'` not the value of the binding

```
.directive('directiverestrict',function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            // I want to get the value of the binding enclosed in the elements directive without ngModels
            console.log(elem[0].textContent) //----> returns '{{binding}}'
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `$interpolate` service, eg

```
.directive('logContent', function($log, $interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {
      $log.debug($interpolate(element.text())(scope));
    }
  };
});
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h19TQwo6qqiGSe5t8mh0?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

```
 <span directiverestrict bind-value="binding"> {{binding}} </span>
```

SCRIPT

```
directive("directiverestrict", function () {
   return {
           restrict : "A",
           scope : {
                      value : '=bindValue'
                   },
           link : function (scope,ele,attr) {
                alert(scope.value); 
              }
      }
});
```

Comment: supposedly i do not want to add any scope attributes? is it posible to get it in another way?

Answer (score 2):

During the link phase the inner bindings are not evaluated, the easiest hack here would be to use `$timeout` service to delay evaluation of inner content to next digest cycle, such as

```
$timeout(function() {
   console.log(elem[0].textContent);
},0);
```

Comment: FYI, `0` is the default timeout interval

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-transclude.  Be sure to set transclude: true on the directive as well.  I was under the impression this was only needed to render the text on the page.  I was wrong.  This was needed for me to be able to get the value into my link function as well.